# Multiple Swipe views

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

So I'm trying to create an app that changes a label based on the direction you swipe. However, instead of being able to swipe anywhere on the screen I'd like it to only swipe on a specific view. I put a new view on the .xib file and used that view for the location of touches and named it leftView, but it still uses the whole screen. I'm using a touchesBegan and touchesMoved method so I can use diagonals.
Here's a bit of the code I'm using:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:leftView];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:leftView];
CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);
if ((deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance) && currentPosition.x < gestureStartPoint.x){
    label.text = @"Left Horizontal swipe detected";
}
else if((deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance) && currentPosition.x > gestureStartPoint.x){
    label.text = @"Right Horizontal swipe detected";
}
else if ((deltaY >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaX <= kMaximumVariance) && currentPosition.y < gestureStartPoint.y){
    label.text = @"Up Vertical swipe detected";
}
else if ((deltaY >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaX <= kMaximumVariance) && currentPosition.y > gestureStartPoint.y){
    label.text = @"Down Vertical swipe detected";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you're after by adding two `UIGestureRecognizer`s (one for right swipe and another for left swipe) to the `UIView` that you want to receive the swipes.

Apple's [SimpleGestureRecognizer sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460) gives a great illustration of how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the identity inspector whether the uiview class is selected for the UIView object in organizer. I guess u have implemented the touchesBegan method in the sub class of UIView.